# Jekyll Error: "Image" not found while using template

Tags: css, jekyll

I'm using the [Spectral](http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/spectral/) theme for Jekyll, and I'm running into issues with changing the images in the page. To do this, I changed the file path in the CSS. When I try to build the site, the following error shows up in the terminal:

> [(date and time)] ERROR '/images/picturename.jpg' not found.

That's odd because I made sure that 'picturename.jpg' is indeed in the folder. This only happens when I use my own images, when the default images that came with the theme is loaded the error doesn't happen, even though they're in the same folder!

Comment: Did you try to edit line `1678,1803,1824` in the `css\main.scss` file

Comment: @AbdulHadi Yes, I've tried editing those lines in the scss file. I've also tried renaming the original sample photo to a temporary name and the photo I want to "banner.jpg" (the name of the sample photo included in the download), and now it says it can't find banner.jpg either...